# How to handle irrevelant texts with FastText predictions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fasttext

I am creating a model which aims to classify my text in one of the defined classes, for example computer science, sport and politics.
For example, the training file could look like this :

```
__label__computer_science I don't think this processor is enough to do what you want
__label__sport I go hiking with my friends
...
```

And could the model can be trained using :

```py
model = fasttext.train_supervised(input = 'model.train', lr = 1, epoch = 25)
```

But I would like to have the possibility to detect the texts that are not part of any of these classes, for example, the text "It's sunny today" does not belong to any class, but my model always "finds" a class with a confidence score higher than 0.90. This text could be considered as sport:

```py
model.predict("It's sunny today")
```

would give this output :

```py
(('__label__sport', '__label__politics', '__label__computer_science'), (9.96934652e-01, 3.05534799e-03, 1.00000034e-05)
```

I thought of training my model with a new class "others", but given the range of possibilities for this class, it would be difficult to create a large enough training set.
I would like to know if fasttext offers a solution to this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to have FastText’s supervised mode ever tell you ‘other’, you’d have to provide it positive examples of an ‘other’ class during training.

That’s what fits its limits & assumptions – & might work OK, for your purposes. But of course the only way to know is to try.

If your target deployment use will encounter texts that you can identify as ‘other’, start sampling that source early! Pick a few hundred such texts as your ‘other’ seed set, and see if that helps.

Or, just reuse some other big source of texts that you suspect will resemble your eventual ‘other’ texts, but not (strongly) in your other classes. (A few stragglers shouldn’t hurt, but you could also try discarding such repurposed texts if they include any of the most-infornative terms in your base class training texts.)

Adjust the size/sources/filtering of this synthetic ‘other’ set based ob your observations of what’s achieving the desired effect. That might at first be eyeballing it manually, in an ad hoc fashion - but should transition to you having a repeatable automated scoring system, with trial data you gradually curate over time to include tough cases.

There are some techniques for ‘one class classification’, where you only have positive examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification (OCC)

You could potentially treat *all* your existing labeled texts of known classes as one ‘non-other’ class, and use such a technique as a separate step, before FastText supervised classification.

But I don’t see OCC used much, & suspect finding good implementations, & tuning/evaluating to report ‘other’ well, could be harder than the approaches discussed above. There’s no shortage of actual texts in the world that aren’t in your finite set of classes-of-interest!